# Graph of a Function

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

> Given
>   $$
> f(x) = \frac{1}{x – 2} + 5
> \qquad
> x\neq 2
> $$
>   Explain how the graph of $f$ can be obtained from the graph of $\frac1x$ by using appropriate translations. Include the image set of the function $f$.

Comment: C'mon Bob, give us a bit more effort...

Comment: Do your homework, Bob.

Comment: Jeez! Sorry guys it's my first time.

Answer (score 1):

Let $g(x) = \frac1x$, then
$$
f(x) = g(x-2)+5
$$
That is, you basically do a change of coordinates from $y=g(x)$ to $\hat y = g(\hat x)$ where
$$
\begin{cases}
\hat x & = x-2 \\
\hat y & = y-5
\end{cases}
$$
$\hat x$ accounts for a horizontal translation of $+2$, i.e. of two units to the right, and $\hat y$ for a vertical translation of $+5$, i.e. of two units upward.
In the end the graph of $f(x)$ is that of $\frac1x$ translated by vector $(2,5)$.

Finally graphically deduce the image of $f(x)$ from that of $\frac1x$ which is clearly $\mathbb R\setminus 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Have a nice graph:

[image: Bob's homework]

([Large Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IT8g4.png))

Comment: Well, what a treat thank you very much.